# Will busy loop calling function that internally created an anonymous object create overhead?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am creating a Kotlin app with Android. I used `suspendCoroutine` to convert a callback API to a `suspend function`. Currently I have the following code.

```
while(true){
   newSuspendFunction().let{ value ->
     //do some simple work
   }

   yield()
}
```

And my `newSuspendFunction` is along the side of

```
suspend fun newSuspendFunction() {
  suspendCoroutine { cont ->
     InterfaceWithCallback { value ->
        cont.resume(value)
     }.let { myInterfaceWithCallback ->
        registerInterfaceWithCallback(myInterfaceWithCallback)
     }
  }
}
```

Question is, does this introduce runtime overhead and reinstantiate `InterfaceWithCallback` each time the function is called or does it create a singleton somewhere in memory and performs optimizations?

**Edit:**
I needed to convert a multi-shot api, so `callbackFlow` is a valid solution here.

Comment: *does this introduce runtime overhead* - compared to what? Using `registerInterfaceWithCallback` directly (without suspend fun wrapper) also requires you to pass a callback object, and if you need to do something different every time, you will need a different implementation of that callback. Please provide a snippet of code that you would like to compare the suspend function call to.

Comment: It might be useful to share what you're trying to do on a bigger scale, by the way. Maybe there are better approaches altogether. For instance, if this is a multi-shot callback you might want to wrap it as a flow instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `newSuspendFunction` does create a new instance of `InterfaceWithCallback` each time, because the lambda captures the continuation `cont`, which is different every time you call `suspendCoroutine`.

That being said, it doesn't mean this overhead will be significant. Short-lived objects might not be a big problem for the garbage collector. You would need to measure whether this really has a measurable impact on performance.

Also, you don't need `yield()` in your loop since `newSuspendFunction` is already a suspend function that actually suspends.

And last but not least, why these `.let` calls? I find it more readable to avoid nesting blocks when you can. You can use variables instead of `let` :)

---

EDIT: Now, your use case seems to need a `Flow` instead of a suspend function, because your callback is called repeatedly. You can use `callbackFlow` to wrap your callback-based API:

```kotlin
// replace Int with whatever type you're dealing with
fun someUsefulName(): Flow<Int> = callbackFlow {
    val callback = InterfaceWithCallback { value ->
        trySendBlocking(value)
    }
    registerInterfaceWithCallback(callback)

    // suspends until the flow collector is cancelled, and unregisters
    awaitClose {
        // there should be some kind of 'unregister' counterpart
        unregisterInterfaceWithCallback(callback)
    }
}
```

---

For reference, here is the decompiled bytecode for your `newSuspendFunction`, where you can see the `new MainJvmKt$newSuspendFunction$2$1(cont)`:

```java
@Nullable
public static final Object newSuspendFunction(@NotNull Continuation $completion) {
    SafeContinuation var2 = new SafeContinuation(IntrinsicsKt.intercepted($completion));
    Continuation cont = (Continuation)var2;
    int var4 = false;
    MainJvmKt$newSuspendFunction$2$1 var5 = new MainJvmKt$newSuspendFunction$2$1(cont);
    InterfaceWithCallback myInterfaceWithCallback = (InterfaceWithCallback)var5;
    int var7 = false;
    registerInterfaceWithCallback(myInterfaceWithCallback);
    Object var10000 = var2.getOrThrow();
    if (var10000 == IntrinsicsKt.getCOROUTINE_SUSPENDED()) {
        DebugProbesKt.probeCoroutineSuspended($completion);
    }

    return var10000 == IntrinsicsKt.getCOROUTINE_SUSPENDED() ? var10000 : Unit.INSTANCE;
}

@Metadata(
   mv = {1, 9, 0},
   k = 3,
   d1 = {"\u0000\u000e\n\u0000\n\u0002\u0010\u0002\n\u0000\n\u0002\u0010\b\n\u0000\u0010\u0000\u001a\u00020\u00012\u0006\u0010\u0002\u001a\u00020\u0003H\n¢\u0006\u0002\b\u0004"},
   d2 = {"<anonymous>", "", "value", "", "callback"}
)
final class MainJvmKt$newSuspendFunction$2$1 implements InterfaceWithCallback {
   // $FF: synthetic field
   final Continuation $cont;

   public final void callback(int value) {
      Continuation var2 = this.$cont;
      Integer var3 = value;
      Result.Companion var10001 = Result.Companion;
      var2.resumeWith(Result.constructor-impl(var3));
   }

   MainJvmKt$newSuspendFunction$2$1(Continuation var1) {
      this.$cont = var1;
   }
}
```

This assumes that `InterfaceWithCallback` is declared as:

```kotlin
fun interface InterfaceWithCallback {
    fun callback(value: Int)
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Joffrey! I have a small follow-up question. Since my `InterfaceWithCallback` will continuously return values in its callback (of course breaks the logic now, though is unrelated question anyways), do you think there is some other, more elegant solution I could have used to write this code? Maybe, exposing a flow and then observing it or something similar?

Comment: @brzi_gonzales yeah that's what I thought, hence my comment under your question :) Indeed if this callback is called repeatedly, then you should instead wrap it in a flow, for instance using `callbackFlow`. I'll update my answer

Comment: the only thing I was scared from in this scenario is `trySendBlocking` which might block the thread. That's why I avoided it. I don't want to block the thread, just the coroutine. Will this block it? Documentation says it is safe to use in `runBlocking` though I am not doing that exactly

P.S. In Kotlin I chain everything I can and almost never use variables :D. Forcing the declarative approach like crazy. Just got used to it.

Comment: The function in `InterfaceWithCallback` (which I called `callback` because I don't know your case) is not suspending. If you control it, you could make it `suspend`, but I doubt that's the case. Therefore, it's by definition a blocking function. It doesn't mean it will block for long, every regular non-suspend function is blocking, and it doesn't mean it's bad. This callback function will only block the thread of the caller while no consumer gets the value from the flow. You can add a buffer to avoid this: the values will be stored in the buffer and `trySendBlocking` will never block

Comment: Thank you, last question I swear. Since, in `callbackFlow` I got access to the `ProducerScope`, would it make sense to just do the following:
```callbackFlow { InterfaceWithCallback { value -> launch{ send(value) } } }
```

Which one would be considered better in this case? I would assume that launching a new coroutine can cause race conditions related to the order in which `value`s are coming whereas `trySend` doesn't

Comment: Yes, launching coroutines like this could mess up with the order of elements and technically you don't gain anything compared to just setting an unlimited buffer for the channel. You would just create a queue of coroutines instead of creating a queue of values in the channel